# Checkboxlist styling in VB/ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, checkboxlist

I am trying to style a checkboxlist control in VB/ASP.NET  below:

```
Dim MultipleSelect As New CheckBoxList
MultipleSelect.RepeatColumns = 1
MultipleSelect.ID = "checkboxlist_" & IssueScoreControl.IssueScoreControl_PK
MultipleSelect.CssClass = "chkListStyle"
bla bla
```

and the style class "chkListStyle" is as follows:

```
<style>
        .chkListStyle input { float:left; }
        .chkListStyle label { float:left; width:80%; padding-left:3px; }
</style>
```

I want the text next to the check box. If there are more than 1 words, it worls all fine. 
 But For some reason, when the text of an item added to the checkboxlist is a single word, the word appears in the next line (below the check box). How do I solve this? Please let me know if anyone is aware.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the CSS:

```
white-space:nowrap;
```

to prevent wrapping of text, and see if that works.  If not, examine the CSS to ensure the CheckBoxList is not rendering something specifically to cause this.